# XML Serialization not reading Attribute values

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to serialize an XML into a Class, PostalAddress. The Postal Address looks like this

```
 public class PostalAddress
{
    public string DeliverTo { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("isoCountryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

The input XML document is

```
<PostalAddress>
   <DeliverTo>SomeBody</DeliverTo>
   <Street>Some Street Address</Street>
   <City>MyCity</City>
   <PostalCode>US-1013</PostalCode>
   <Country isoCountryCode="US">US</Country>
</PostalAddress>
```

The C# code I am using for Serializing is

Now After Deserialization, I am able to see the values from XML in the corresponding properties but It is Missing the Attribute Value which I wanted to map into a Property, CountryCode.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PostalAddress));
var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse}
PostalAddress postalAddress;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputDocument.ToString()), xmlReaderSettings))
{
     postalAddress= (PostalAddress)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Can you please help where am I missing things here?``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlAttribute` will not work in the context you're using it, because it's looking at the element `PostalAddress`, which has no attributes. The attribute you want, `isoCountryCode`, is on the sub element `Country`.

To make this work you need to define another class for the `Country` element. For example, you could use classes like the below.

```
public class PostalAddress
{
    public string DeliverTo { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }    
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Country")]
public class Country 
{
    [XmlAttribute("isoCountryCode")]
    public string IsoCountryCode { get; set;}
    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, if you can't change your class structure, you can look at custom deserialisation with the `IXmlSerializable` interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I got it working now :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create class for Country element with two property named CountryCode & Text...

```
public class PostalAddress
{
    public string DeliverTo { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }

}

public class Country
{
    [XmlAttribute("isoCountryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I got it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `XmlAttribute`-attribute, the attribute should be located on the element that corresponds to the class. In other words, if you would structure your XML document like this, the attribute would be de-serialized into the property:

```
<PostalAddress isoCountryCode="US">...</PostalAddress>
```

However, of you add another class for the country, you can deserialize the XML properly:

```
public class PostalAddress
{
    public string DeliverTo { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Country")]
    public CountryCode CountryCode;
}

public class CountryCode
{
    [XmlAttribute("isoCountryCode")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I got it working now :)